# What does $X_1,X_2,...\stackrel{ind}{\sim}N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ mean?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, notation

**Question:** What does $X_1,X_2,...\stackrel{ind}{\sim}N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ mean?

I know what $X_1,X_2,...\stackrel{i.i.d.}{\sim} N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ means: $X_1,X_2,...$ are independently and identically distributed normally with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. I used to think that $\stackrel{ind}{\sim}$ just meant distributed independently, but wouldn't this imply that the $X_1,X_2,...$ are also distributed identically?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've seen neither of these notations, but both mean that $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are iid $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: You are correct.